# Need help on terminating a thread when another thread is complete in python

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to create a simple UI for Bluetooth. The UI has a root window with 3 buttons.

- Scan
- Discover
- Quit

During Scan and Discover click, i wanted to create a `Toplevel` window with a `label` and `progressbar`, and their corresponding function running behind the `Toplevel` window.

Here is my code:

```
import threading
import ttk
import time
from Tkinter import *
from bluetooth import *

def bluethscn():
    ...
    do_something...
    ...
    return

def msgwindow(msg):
    window1 = Toplevel()
    frame1 = Frame(window1)
    frame1.pack()
    label = Label(frame1, text=msg)
    label.pack()
    frame2 = Frame(window1)
    frame2.pack()
    pb_hd = ttk.Progressbar(frame2, orient='horizontal', mode='indeterminate')
    pb_hd.pack()
    pb_hd.start(6)

def discover():
    print "searchine for nearby devices..."
    nearby_devs = discover_devices(8,True,True)
    print "nearby_devs = ", nearby_devs

def start_discover():
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=msgwindow("searching..."), args=())
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=discover, args=())
    t1.start()
    t2.start()

root=Tk()
label = Label(root, text="Root Window").pack()
butn_quit = Button(root, text="Quit", command= root.quit)
butn_quit.pack()
butn_dcov = Button(root, text="Discover", command=start_discover)
butn_dcov.pack()
butn_scan = Button(root, text="Scan", command=bluethscn)
butn_scan.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I followed [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EvbA3qVMGaw) example in creating threads. The issue here is im getting the Toplevel window only after the `Discover` or `Scan` function is complete.

I need some little help on how to initiate the thread. And i also want to destroy the Toplevel window once the respective function is done ie,. Toplevel window to be destroyed after `Discover` or `Scan` function is complete

***Update:***

I modified the code little. Previously i just created one single thread. Now i made 2 threads to do the jobs simultaneously, and now it works.

But the problem is, after `discover` function is done, the toplevel window keeps on running. How do i quit the toplevel window when the discover function is done, ie,. stop/destroy `t1` thread when `t2` thread finishes.
If i add `t1.join()`, the same happens. Both process occurs parallely, but when `t2` is done, `t1` keeps running

How do I close/terminate `t1` when `t2` is completed ?

Comment: I don't know if this is your _only_ problem, but you can't directly supply arguments to the target of a Thread. You have to pass them as the `args` parameter, like `t2 = threading.Thread(target=msgwindow, args=("Communicating...",))`.

Comment: I tried that before. when i give `args=("communicating",)` or `args=("searching",)` nothing happens. Not even the `Discover` or `Scan` function's able to complete. say for example if i click `Discover`, i get the "`searching for nearby devices"`, but the `discover_device` line never gets executed at all.

Comment: Like Kevin said you have the thread starting wrong. You call the `msgwindow()` function and pass the _result_ of that function as target for the thread. The result of that function is `None` so nothing is started at all in that thread.

Comment: The next problem you may run into is that the GUI should not manipulated in another thread than the thread which runs the `mainloop()` function. If you do anyway the program behavior is undefinded. Anything could happen, from nothing to complete crashes of the process. Sidenote: Some keys on your keyboard seem to be unreliably — or more seriously: please don't write `bluethscn()` if you really mean `bluetooth_scan()`.

Comment: @BlackJack, Actually i do get both functions running(the progressbar on toplevel window and searching the nearby bluetooth devices) simultaneously..

Comment: @BlackJack, if running a tiny toplevel GUI window containing just a progress bar in a thread would cause unpredictable behavior of the program, then what would be the best way to do so ?

Comment: @arvindh: Change the GUI just from the main thread and communicate with other worker threads via `Queue.Queue` instances or other thread safe mechanisms. You can poll regularly from the GUI thread with the `after()` method on widgets.